# HTML table cell increase symbol font size without increasing text font size

Tags: html

As shown in the attached image, I have a table cell with some text along with a symbol.  I'd like to bump up the size of the symbol while leaving the size of the text as is.  Additionally, I'd like the text and the symbol to be vertically center-aligned.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a special `font-size` for element contains icon, also use `display:flex` and `align-items: center` for alinged vertically:

```css
td{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
i.fa{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
2 warnings <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

th { font-size: 26px;}
td { font-size: 26px;}

Comment: How does this help? as he/she needs to increase the icon size but not the font size.. this will increase font size as well..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I should have added this to the original question.  Here's the code I'm trying ...  
`<td> 2 skipped <span style="font-size: 32px">&#9755;</span></td>`  
This does the trick of increasing the size of the symbol.  However, the vertical alignment is off and it's increasing the row height.  Is there a way to overcome this?